# Transformación de un conjunto de caracteres en un arreglo a una variable tipo char

Tags: c

Estuve intentando realizar una impresión de un conjunto de caracteres de un arreglo a una variable tipo `char` como muestra en el código, pero simplemente no imprime nada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() 
{
    char c[10][10];
    strcpy(c[0],'1234');
    char dato = c[0];
    printf("%c",c);
    return 0;
}
```

La función de salida es NADA.

Lo único que quiero hacer, es pasar datos de un conjunto de caracteres de una matriz, a una variable tipo char. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: No, no es posible pasar los datos de X fila de una matriz a una variable de tipo char, ya que solo puede almacenar únicamente un dato. Lo que puedes hacer es almacenar los datos en un array. Por ejemplo: `strcpy(datos, c[0]);`, sin embargo, `datos` debe ser definido como un array, ej: `char datos[10]`. Aunque sigo sin entender porque quieres hacer esto, lo veo innecesario.

Comment: `char dato = c[0];` ¿Recibiste advertencias del compilador en esta línea? Si no, debes habilitar las advertencias (-Wall con gcc, /Wall o /W3 con Microsoft VC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Lo único que quiero hacer, es pasar datos de un conjunto de caracteres de una matriz, a una variable tipo char. ¿Alguna idea?

Si. Mi idea es que tienes una seria confusión de términos que impiden entender lo que estás haciendo mal.

1. **Primera confusión**: No puedes pasar un conjunto de caracteres a una variable tipo `char`, de la misma manera que no puedes meter en una plaza de parquin más de un coche:

   [image]
   [image]

   Una variable tipo `char` guarda un (UN, UNO SOLO) `char`, no un conjunto de ellos.
2. **Segunda confusión**: Confundes comillas simples (`''`) y comillas dobles (`""`). Las cadenas de texto van entre comillas dobles: `"Hola"` si usas comillas simples para delimitar cuatro caracteres, en realidad lo que tienes es un literal entero multicaracter:

   - `'1234'` es un entero.
   - `"1234"` es una cadena de caracteres.

   El entero `'1234'` tiene como valor 825.373.492 que en hexadecimal es 0x31323334 que viene a ser la concatenación de los valores 0x31, 0x32, 0x33 y 0x34 que se corresponden a los caracteres `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` y `'4'`, aunque el valor final depende de la implementación del compilador.

   No te imprime nada porque en la copia `strcpy(c[0],'1234')` no has copiado la cadena `"1234"` en `c[0]` si no que has copiado lo que sea que hubiera en la dirección de memoria `0x31323334` a `c[0]` y en dicha dirección podria poder ser posible que no hubiera nada imprimible.

- **Tercera confusión**: Las formaciones de dos dimensiones como `char c[10][10]` son punteros a punteros (un puntero por cada dimensión: `char **c`), cuando pides imprimir el primer carácter de la primera cadena de tu formación de dos dimensiones, debes des-referenciar doblemente, no debes usar el nombre de la formación tal cual:

  ```
  printf("%c", c);   // Mal: c es 'char **' no 'char'.
  printf("%c", **c); // Bien.
  ```

La solución a tu problema es que entiendas los errores que has cometido, uses comillas dobles y des-referencies los punteros:

```
char c[10][10];
strcpy(c[0],"1234"); // Cadena de caracteres
char *dato = c[0];   // c[0] es de tipo 'char *' no de tipo 'char'
printf("%c", **c);   // Doble des-referencia de 'c'.
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzBCsIwEAXP2a9YIkIaqqTqLeqPlB7CptpAm5Q0FUT89piCh3eZGR4daDT@mfPOeRpX2@N1SdaF43AHcD7hZJwXr@BsBR9gNJiI1Daq26aBLSnS/BbUqq7mzel84ZX@Z9KaFPCGmytsjuXuIfieeI1SUumAxT6t0aPS8M35Bw)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Para que el código funcione has de hacer algunos cambios:

```
int main() 
{
    char c[10][10];
    strcpy(c[0],"1234");  // Las comillas han de ser dobles ya que es un string
    string dato = c[0];   // Definimos dato como un string tú lo tenías como char
    printf("%s",c);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**EL CODIGO EN C SERÍA ASÍ SIN QUE NOS DE ERRORES:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    char c[10][10];
    strcpy(c[0],"1234");  // Las comillas han de ser dobles ya que es un string

    char dato[10]; 
    strcpy(dato, c[0]);

    printf("Variable: c[0] : %s\n", c[0]);
    printf("Variable: dato : %s", dato);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En C no existe la clase *String*.

Comment: Qué sentido tiene para ti hacer: char dato = c[0]; Qué finalidad pretendes?

Comment: Te he extendido la respuesta con código testado.